How to make the roof level after separating with CTRL+ R

The box on the right is an extrusion of the polygon. I have separated the extrusion with the polygon through CTRL + R. How do I make the roof of the extrusion and the polygon level again?

It's unclear what you are asking. Can you add an image with an annotation of what you're trying to do and maybe share your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

One way to flatten faces to other faces you can set the Orientation mode to Normal and the pivot point to Active, Then select the face you want to move and then the Face you want to flatten it to.

Press S+Z+0+Enter

If the object/face is oriented correctly, you don't need to use the Normal. You could leave it at Global or Local if that works
Play around with the options, this is one of the most useful tools when modeling
